# R and SQL Query Together Format

Tags: mysql, sql, r

I have the following list of IDs that I am trying to input to a SQL query through R.

```
  ID<-c("‘3CS3PJ478’, ‘N6LQ1CMW1’, ‘4J9GNYHC8’, ‘6H8D3A1P0’")
```

SQL Query in R

```
UKSQL6<-data.frame(sqlQuery(myConn, paste("SELECT TOP 100 [AxiomaDate]
                      ,[RiskModelID] ,[IID],[Factor1],[Factor2],[Factor3],[Factor4]FROM [PortfolioAnalytics].[Data_Axioma].[SecurityExposures]
                      Where AxiomaDate IN (
                        SELECT   MAX(AxiomaDate)
                        FROM     [PortfolioAnalytics].[Data_Axioma].[FactorReturns]
                                  GROUP BY MONTH(AxiomaDate), YEAR(AxiomaDate)
                      AND  IID IN (", paste(ID, collapse = ", "), ")")))
```

Now when I paste the ID (in the last line of the Query) It is not in the correct format so the query is not working. The first and last characters in the ID object are " " which does not work with the SQL query. Is there an easy way I can remove that so they are compatible with my query above?

Comment: Escape the characters with a backslash \

Comment: Sorry can you show me where in the code I could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot pass a list into SQL as a parameter.  So, you have to munge the query string.

I think this does what you want:

```
IID IN ('", paste(ID, collapse = "', '"), "')")))
```

The single quotes are needed for string values.

Comment: This is very close to what I need but the query isn't quite working there. The output of the paste ID in your answer is ...(‘3CS3PJ478’, ‘N6LQ1CMW1’, ‘4J9GNYHC8’, ‘6H8D3A1P0’ ')' . I firstly noticed that SQL works with ' quotations and not ’ which I have above. Also with your solution the last bracket is surrounded by ')' which is not readable in SQL. Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: @user8491385 . . . There are no curly single quotes in this answer, so those are coming from the cut/paste.  The last bracket has only a single quote before it.  I don't know where the outer quote would be coming from.